# Laravel: Custom verification with hash token with slash

Tags: php, laravel, hash, routes, laravel-6

I am trying to create my own custom verify email but it seems that i am at fault somewhere.

The route is working fine but when I encountereed a hashed token with '/' slash somewhere then it says not found. How can I avoid this?

**creating the token**

```
$permission = new Permission();
$permission->user()->associate($isPermitted_user);
$permission->token = Hash::make(now());
$permission->save();
```

**creating my URL**

```
$permission = Permission::find($this->permission_id);
    $permission_url = url('/permission/'.$permission->token);
    $user = $permission->user;
    $data = array(
        'permission_url' => $permission_url,
        'name' => $notifiable->name,
        'user' => $user,
    );
```

**web.php**

```
  Route::get('/permission/{token}', 'PermissionsController@permission')->middleware('verified');
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#parameters-encoded-forward-slashes ... or encode the hash in a way to not include the '/' character

Comment: properly show us your code. with the function name, how you called and where you called etc ... not just raw data. Read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

From Laravel's documentation on encoding forward slashes.

> Encoded Forward Slashes
>
> The Laravel routing component allows all characters except /. You must explicitly allow / to be part of your placeholder using a where condition regular expression:
>
> Route::get('search/{search}', function ($search) {
> return $search;
> })->where('search', '.*');

That means in your case allowing '/' to be part of the placeholder, you need to use the where route condition regular expression on your token parameter:

```php
 Route::get('/permission/{token}', 'PermissionsController@permission')->middleware('token')->where('token', '.*');
```

`Inspired by the comment by lagbox`

Answer (score 0):

To remove slashes in Hash:

```
str_replace('/', '', Hash::make(now()));
```

Comment: This is a bad idea, you should not remove anything form a hash, it will make the hash useless.